# Check for HTML5 with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that contains some JS to update the browser history (`pushState()`, using HTML5). As IE8 does not support HTML5 users are being told that the page contains an error. While this doesn't deminish the functionality of the page, it doesn't look very professional, so I'm wondering if there is a check to see if the users browser supports HTML5 before running this code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/** Update history.state() (for back/forward links) */
var object = {
    ajax_string: '<?php echo make_ajax_string(); ?>',
    security: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('updated-page-nonce'); ?>',
};
window.history.replaceState(object, '<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>', '<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>');
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check if the `replaceState` method is available before running the code:

```
if(window.history.replaceState) {
    //Your code
}
```

If `replaceState` is `undefined` (which will be the case in browsers that do not support it) then the statement evaluates to `false` and the code is not executed.

Comment: +1 - Feature detection FTW. seems a bit overkill to use Modernizr just for this.

Comment: @James Many thanks, as a quick fix this has solved the problem.

Comment: Even though I suggested Modernizr, I agree!

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/).

Comment: Thanks Ian, this looks good but may be a little over the top for where I am right now. Will bear in mind for the future though.

Comment: Ah, fair enough if you're only looking for one specific thing then I agree it's over the top.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to check if new HTML5 History APIs (`pushState`, `replaceState`, `popState`) are supported by the browser, or use 
[History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) to have full cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
if (!!(window.history && history.replaceState)) {
    // has replaceState support
}
```