# Proper JS fallback techniques

Tags: javascript, exception, fallback

**Not looking for a technique that will just solve history issues.**

I've recently started using some HTML 5 features, specifically the `history.replaceState()` and `history.setState()`. Of course, older browsers don't support this:

[image]

and was wondering if there is a proper way to fallback to another method that is supported or just not call it all on **any method not supported by user browser version, not just `history`** rather than throwing an exception.

Would the technique be on a *per case* use? Or is there an all encompassing glorious clean way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check for HTML5 with JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900550/check-for-html5-with-js)

Comment: While it does bring up the same question, it is asking for a general way of falling back properly and uses `history` object as an example.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty, please review question. That question you suggested does not satisfy the question being asked here.

Comment: As mentioned in that other question, you can use Modernizr to catch a lot of newer web technologies.  If you know specifically what you need fallbacks for, look for "polyfills" for them.  Libraries like jQuery and underscore.js have built in fallbacks to account for older browsers in some situations.  You/your dev. team just need to define what browsers and version you are willing to support and test everything in each to find any potential missing polyfills.